# How can I make two apps find and connect via LAN?

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, sockets, lan

I need to scan the LAN for similar app running and then establish connection between them so I can exchange some commands between them. I code in C#.
The only way I've found so far is to generate IP's and ping them... but it'd take too many time. Is there a quicker way?
Maybe it can be done via WIN_API and then wrapped by C# [DllImport("..")] extern methods?

Comment: Are these applications guaranteed to be in the same VLAN?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use UDP to broadcast your presence so that other applications could hear you and establish a socket with you for further communication.

Comment: This might take some special network configuration if this is deployed with V-LANs.

Answer (score 0):

This gets a lot easier if you add a "rendezvous" or "discovery" server. It can be very simple - add/remove "active client" IPs and query for list of clients are the essential functions. If you have a central database the clients can access directly you don't need any "server" code at all - just an "active clients" table.